# Getting IP address of all device in local network , windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ip-address, arp

There are multiple posts of this in many forums including this one,
some of them involve using a third party app, and some involves using arp-scan or arpping tool in linux.

I am trying to get an idea as to how to build these kind of applications, so you see I cannot use third party applications.

My question is to how to Get the ip address of all active devices in the local network, IP address are assigned by the Router DHCP, and I dont want to login to router to get the IP addresses it has lended.

using a for-loop in the cmd to scan all the devices with a ping command will take a lot of time,

Now the interesting thing is,
`arp -a` only gives IP addresses to all the devices that my machines has communicated with, Also clearing up the arp table, using arp -d didnt help,

but `net view /all` gave me all the names of the machines in the network, 
and by names i mean computer names.

So is there any command in windows platform that I can do along with netview to also get the ip address, may smething in the powershell ?
I dont want to use any kind of third party app, it will not help me understand the logic behind this.

Comment: You can use `PING` with count 1 and execute batch file with multiple threads to make it fast. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/232225/multithreaded-windows-for-batch-command) may help.

Comment: May **[This](https://serverfault.com/q/30738/462253)** help you. **:)**

Comment: ok, lemme see..

Comment: wait.exe is not found.. 
any alternative to that? find /v /c "" ?

Comment: ok so using this `for /L %N in (1,1,254) do @ping 192.168.0.%N` command , it kinda updated my arp table and was able to identify like 7 devices. I will try to run this in batch command file.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, let the windows 7 broadcast, then it will get all the IP-to-MAC in the ARP list.

try this:

1.ping your **broadcast IP address**.
2.run the **arp -a**

The broadcast IP is dependent on your IP address, if your IP is x.x.x.x/24, the broadcast Ip address is x.x.x.255.

Now you can see all the IP in the local network.

Comment: the dhcp address range is 192.168.0.100 to 199.
Even in this case I think my broadcast address is 192.168.0.255
which i do, it replies with 100% loss, according to u the arp table in my system will be updated with all the ip address of all the computers in my network? 
which can be viewed with arp -a ?

Comment: I can only see 2 systems, but i have 4 right now

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a script/program that pings one-at-a-time to all the network possibilites inside of a network. For e.g, if the default gateway is 192.168.100.1, we have to programatically ping each address in the whole network. I do not have access to the program but the algorithm could be:

1. use ipconfig to figure out the default gateway (router ip) and subnet mask. Let's say default gateway is 192.168.100.1 and mask is 255.255.255.0, or 192.168.100.1/24.
2. Use a script to ping all the way from 192.168.100.0 till 192.168.100.254
3. record each event and see the result.

I looked this up and tried all the solutions mentioned above as well as in other solutions but none of them worked. Then it hit me - a powershell or cmd script file could do it.

The easier way of course is to have the router access so that all the connected devices / nodes can be identified with ease.